# How to change length of header from page 2 onwards?

Tags: pdftex, header-footer, memoir

I want to add a fixed size header from page 2 in my document which takes almost half of the page. How to set such large header for pages from page 2 without affecting page 1 header height. MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lfoot{\thepage\ -- next foot}
\geometry{a4paper,inner=12mm,outer=12mm,top=10mm,bottom=15mm,footskip=1mm}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
\fancyhf{}\lfoot{first foot}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the same way as in the other question where you find this code: set the geometry and the header so that it fits for page 2 and following, and then use \vspace*{-x..} to move the text on page one onwards.

Comment: As Ulrike already pointed out, how is this question different from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503174/how-to-assign-different-footer-from-page-2-onwards